# How do I evaluate $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i+1$ and $\sum_{i=2}^{n-1} \log i^{n}$?

Tags: summation

I'm having trouble with finding the sums of the problem $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^{i+1}$ and $\sum_{i=2}^{n-1} \log i^{n}$

I've thought it over and don't know where to start with either of these problems.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What do you get if you multiply the first sum by two? Is it similar in any way to the original version?

Comment: Are you familiar with geometric sums (for the first sum)? The typical way of finding a geometric sum is denoting the sum by $S$, multiplying the sum by the common ratio $r$, and then subtracting them. For the second sum, keep in mind that $\log \left(i^n\right) = n\log(i)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip: call the first sum $S_1$. Then $S_1 = 2S_1 - S_1 = 2^{n+1} - 2$.

Call the second sum $S_2$. Since $\log x^y = y\log x$, $S_2 = \sum\limits_{i=2}^{n-1} n \log i = n \sum\limits_{i=2}^{n-1} \log i$. Now use that $\log x + \log y = \log xy$ to deduce that $S_2 = n\log\,(n-1)!$ .

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm confused on why you multiplied the first sum by 2 and subtracted by 2

Comment: That's the typical way geometric sums are found. Multiplying the the ratio ($2$ in this case) simplifies once you subtract the sums. Check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) for the general case. Notice how all the middle terms cancel out, simplifying everything.

Comment: The first sum is very “famous”, so I proceeded to sum it in the canonical way. It’s a geometric series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series